# Why no error of return value?

Tags: returndata

In the following code, I am returning a wrong value but there is no syntax error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract C1 {
  function g(uint a) public returns (uint) {  f(a); }
  function f(uint) public returns(bool) { } 
}
```

function f(..) returns a boolean value but function g(..) requires uint.

Somebody please guide me why I am not getting any syntax error?

Comment: Elaborate more on why you think there should be a problem. The functions return different types. That's okay.

Comment: Its violating the function g(...)' s return policy. function g(...) says that it would return uint but function g() is calling function f() whose return statement says that it would return bool which is against the return statement of g().  Is there any respect for 'returns (uint)' statement in function g()?

Comment: It doesnt actually compile without ; after  g. They are independent.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand this term "; after g".

Comment: Nvmd. Im working from a phone.  `fa (a)` is not assigned or returned. If you `return f (a);` you will get a type mismatch. Hope that answers the original question.

Comment: 'return' is necessary for returning values. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others who come across this.

The statement

```
f(a);
```

invokes the function `f()` and ignores the response. The expected syntax error is raised when the return value of `f()` (bool) is explicitly returned:

```
function g(uint a) public returns(uint) {  return f(a); }
```

`f()` cannot be returned from `g()` because `function g() ... returns(uint)` and `function f() ... returns(bool)`. `bool` is not `uint` so the types are incompatible, as expected.

Hope it helps.